# What's with this "approved for Pesach" tape?

Tags: passover, hechsher-certification

[image: Masking tape. The inside of the roll is printed with Hebrew information, including "*Me-ushar lepesach: me-ushar mita'am habada"tz*"]
[image: Masking tape. The inside of the roll is printed with Hebrew information, including "*Me-ushar lepesach: me-ushar mita'am habada"tz*"]

That's masking tape from the hardware store, with an "approved for Pesach" label by the Badatz. What??

Comment: +1, good eye....might just be a marketing ploy. Note also that the Badatz symbol [generally](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/b/b2/Badatz_logo.gif) looks [fancier](http://www.jerusalemkoshernews.com/wp-content/uploads/R-Rubin-symbol-Hebrew5.jpg) than that, and will tell you which city / rabbi is in charge of the *hashgacha*.

Comment: Right, i noticed it didn't look like a usual hechsher.

Comment: Badatz stands for Bet Din Tzedek. When people say Badatz casually they're usually referring to Badatz [Ha-Eidah HaCheredi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edah_HaChareidis), however other organizations use the same acronym. In fact if you look closely at [their logo](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/b/b2/Badatz_logo.gif), you'll notice it says "Badatz SHEL Eidah HaCharedi". Take a look at [these images](http://www.jerusalemkoshernews.com/popular-recognized-kashrut-agencies-in-israel/) of certifications in Israel and you'll see a handful that include the acronym badatz in there somewhere.

Comment: Did you try calling the importer, Khan, whose number is listed on the label?

Comment: More money more honey

Comment: Note that the logo is not the "badatz eidah hachareidis", which does not certify things for Pesach other than staple foods.

Comment: I remember hearing somewhere that some of the ingredients in tape might have elements of Chametz in it. It doesn't seem that far-fetched to believe something like that. Another example of something that doesn't seem like it would have Chametz in it is Iodized Salt. Apparently the Iodizing process contains Chametz. Especially given the severity of Chametz on Pesach, I can understand why people are particularly careful of anything that might contain Chametz.

Comment: @IsaacMoses No, we didn't. Might be worth it. :)

Comment: AIUI, Masking tape is a paper based tape. Paper can contain starch, which may be chametz (or at least kitnyot). Presumably someone has checked and this tape is free from any suspicion of chametz in its manufacture. Exactly who checked (i.e. which Bada"tz) is another matter.

Comment: @Epicentre I understand when it comes to paper plates, cups, etc that people are using for food, even if i consider it slightly overboard. But with this, whatever starch is in there is not edible, and in all likelihood, isn't even going to touch food!

Comment: @ Scimonster Don't forget that chametz must not be posessed or found at all, and presumably the haredim, who are renowned for their strictness, don't want to take the chance that there could be some chametz there, even if a dog wouldn't eat it (i.e. it's not actually chametz)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Baking hand shmura matzahs involves placing the matzahs in an oven using long wooden poles. Out of concern that some dough may be stuck on to the pole the poles are sanded down after use.

Some avoid the whole issue of stuck dough and cover the poles with paper using masking tape as the adhesive - a common practice in matzah chaburos. Since the matzah comes into contact with the masking tape it is necessary to ensure that the tape adhesive is kosher for pesach as  starch based adhesives sourced from chametz may be used. Google "starch based adhesive" for more information.

Comment: Welcome back, Yoni! +1